# Unresolved reference: viewModelScope - Kotlin Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin, kotlin-android-extensions, kotlin-coroutines

I try to add viewModelScope to a basic viewModel but android studio doesn't recognize it.

I tried to change my gradle build file with some solution I found but nothing works.

Here an extract of my build.gradle app

```
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.2.0-alpha01"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.2.0-alpha01"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate:1.0.0-alpha01"
kapt "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:2.2.0-alpha01"
```

When I type viewModelScope in my viewModel it say `Unresolved reference: viewModelScope`.

Comment: I have it working using `androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.1.0-beta01`.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

for now its in alpha, so please update your gradle to use the following dependencies:

```
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.2.0"
```

Answer (score 25):

In my case i forgot to extends ViewModel in that class, the class you use for viewModelScope must be like `yourModelClass : ViewModel()` in kotlin and for java `yourModelClass extends ViewModel`

Hope its help

Answer (score 8):

I've had the same issue and I've just imported:

`"androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.2.0-rc03" 
"androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.2.0-rc03"`

Even though I thought fragment-ktx was not really related. Took me a while to figure that out. Hope it helps!

Comment: Can someone explains why "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx" is related to viewModelScope??

Answer (score 5):

Also check that you are in the correct file. I had the same problem for a moment and I came to this page, but later on, I realized I accidentally tried to run `viewModelScope.launch` on my *Fragment*.

`viewModelScope.launch` is only available in your ViewModels and
`lifecycleScope.launch` in your lifecycle aware components.

Answer (score 3):

For latest version of the artifact refer 
[Maven Repository Android Lifecycle ViewModel Kotlin Extensions](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/androidx.lifecycle/lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx)

In app level build.gradle file add the following :-

```
def lifecycle_version = "2.2.0-rc03"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
kapt "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:$lifecycle_version"
```

Don't forget to add `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'` at the top of app/build.gradle file

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you are not extending the activityViewModel with **ViewModel** class

```
class SampleActivityViewModel: ViewModel() {

 fun getData(){
     viewModelScope.launch{
       // Make an API call
     }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`viewModelScope` was introduced with release `2.1.0`, see [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle#version_210_3).

Check whether `lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx-2.2.0-alpha01.aar` is installed. For me there is no error message with the settings you wrote. However, there is an error message when using an earlier version:

```
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.0.0"
```

But this works:

```
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.1.0"
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove below config from **build.gradle(:app)**

```
configurations {
    all {
        exclude group: 'androidx.lifecycle', module: 'lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In **Build.gradle** *(App Level)*

Change your code from:

`def lifecycle_version = "2.0.0"` or if you are using any lower version than this to:

`def lifecycle_version = "2.2.0"`

`viewModelScope` was launched in `2.2.0` version of lifecycle module so you won't find it before that.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've got two different versions of the androidX lifecycle libraries in use.

Change your `app/build.gradle` to be:

```
...
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.2.0-alpha01"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.2.0-alpha01"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate:2.2.0-alpha01"
kapt "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:2.2.0-alpha01"
...
```

Answer (score 0):

*ViewModelScope* only added in version 2.2.0, not available on higher versions too. I tried with 2.6.0 but got same error.

Answer (score 0):

your `ViewModel` must extend `androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel`. if it doesn't, the Android studio doesn't recognize `viewModelScope`.

```
class RegisterViewModel() : ViewModel()  {
    fun postRegister(registerBody: RegisterBody) = viewModelScope.lunch{

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

adding `lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx` implementation didn't work for me.

```
    implementation("androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.8.0")
//    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-view-model-ktx:2.6.2")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.2")
```

Implmenting `activity-ktx` and `lifecycle-runtime-ktx` as above worked

Answer (score 0):

Add `lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx` to your `app/build.gradle` dependency list:

```
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.6.2"
```